# how to make the linkHtmlOptions of Yii framework's CGridView appear as an image icon and when clicked, triggers a javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, lightbox

here's the part where i need help in my CGridView of Yii framework web app

```
  array(
       'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
       'linkHtmlOptions'=>array("onclick"=>"$('.fancybox').fancybox()"),
       'header'=>'Image',
  ),
```

currently, when i view that at the front-end, it shows "Link" as a hyperlink..
what i want to happen is, it will show a clickable image icon like e.g /images/click_icon.jpg instead of an ordinary word hyperlink, then once it is clicked, it should call this

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

so how to do that in that array i pasted above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
'linkHtmlOptions'=> array("onclick"=>"$('.fancybox').fancybox()"),
```

what you are actually doing is triggering the initialization of all the matched elements by the class selector '.fancybox', on the 'click' event. Although you are doing the initialization, you are not leting fancybox manage the  elements' onclick event in the proper way.

You should have

```
'linkHtmlOptions'=> array("onclick"=>"$('.fancybox').click()"),
```

and, as the instructions at the fancybox site show, put the fancybox initialization in the document.ready event. But if you insist to initialize the fancybox object in the grid, you should write

```
'linkHtmlOptions'=> array("onclick"=>"$('.fancybox').fancybox(); $('.fancybox').click()"),
```

But you may need to wait in between these two calls, would have to test it...

By the way, you are repeating the same link over and over again for every cell in the grid column. Does it make any sense? I would put the link outside the grid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`imageUrl` property of CLinkColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn#imageUrl-detail):

```
array(
   'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
   'linkHtmlOptions'=>array("onclick"=>"$('.fancybox').fancybox()"),
   'header'=>'Image',
   'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/click_icon.jpg'
),
```

Wherever you store the images, that url will have to be provided, for the above example, images are in the project root, hence i used `Yii::app()->baseUrl`.

Comment: I added this 'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/ico-favourite.gif'  but the javascript doesn't work..any idea  why?

Comment: i can (and want to) help you get this working, but you'll have to give me a few details first: 1. which version of fancybox are you using?
2. how are you including the fancybox css and javascript in your view?
3. are you by any chance using an extension for this?